# Parsing text in MS Access forms with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm making a simple form to fill a table. One of the fields is to contain some IDs, either individual, or ranges, like this: "65,73,99-114" with commas and dashes as seperators. I need Access to look up this IDs in another table and provide some data from other columns into the target table. This should be done when a form is submitted.
While this task might sound simple and I know a bit of C# and js, it's my first time being challenged by VBA. I've never dealt with such applications and manuals I found are too vague and/or off-topic. Basically, I need to know what to start from and some general tips, but you're welcome to provide any advanced help.
p.s. Access 2016

Comment: You could use a zero width, zero height text box for each of the segment's and dlookup on these make it easy, or look at using the split function, this will split by a delimiter to an array.

Comment: I need an idea of how to pull data from external table using data from a form.

Comment: That's not your question, but the answer is dlookup, and try googling data from tables in forms, bound controls etc.

Comment: Write some code and show it to us. You know C# and js, this should be easy.

Answer (score 3):

There nothing stopping you from writing some code to “parse” out the given text, and create the required SQL. How such code would look in say c#, or VBA is not really the hard part. The real challenge is writing the code to parse out. (writing code! - the approach would be much the same I c#).

I just air coded this, and it looks to work quite well. This code assumes the column in question is a number column (so no quotes is required around each value).

The code looks like this:

```
 Function MyWhereRanges(strRanges, strField As String) As String

   ' take the raganges, and return a where clause
   Dim vTokens      As Variant
   Dim strRa        As String       ' sql for ranges
   Dim strIn        As String       ' sql for "in" clause
   Dim s            As Variant
   Dim strResult    As String       ' return value

   vTokens = Split(strRanges, ",")
   For Each s In vTokens
      If InStr(s, "-") Then
         ' this is a range - append the range
         If strRa <> "" Then
            strRa = strRa & " and "
         End If
         strRa = strRa & "(" & strField & " between " & _
                 Split(s, "-")(0) & " and " & Split(s, "-")(1) & ")"
      Else
         ' append to the "in" clause
         If strIn = "" Then
            strIn = "(" & strField & " in ("
         Else
            strIn = strIn & ","
         End If
         strIn = strIn & s
      End If
  Next s

  If strIn <> "" Then strIn = strIn & ")) "
  strResult = strIn

  If strRa <> "" Then
     If strResult <> "" Then strResult = strResult & " and "
     strResult = strResult & strRa
  End If

  MyWhereRanges = strResult     ' return the value

 End Function
```

So, from the debug window, you can type in this:

```
? mywhereranges("5,6,12-13,15-25","InvoiceNum")
```

The result from above is this:

```
(InvoiceNum in (5,6))  and 
(InvoiceNum between 12 and 13) and 
(InvoiceNum between 15 and 25)
```

So, in an actual form, you could launch a report or form like this:

```
Dim strSQLwhere       As String
strSQLwhere = MyWhereRanges(Me.txtBoxRanges, "InvoiceNum")
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInvoices", acViewPreview, , strSQLwhere
```